# New to Apple TestFlight

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I'm new to ios development.  I've built an application and now I'm trying to publish it to TestFlight.

I am referencing two tutorials to keep me on track.

I have uploaded the archive through xCode, and logged into iTunes connect.
Both tutorials say something like:

> To enable beta testing of your app, go to the My Apps section on the
>   iTunes Connect home page and click on your app. Select the Prerelease
>   tab and you’ll find your latest build.

But I do not have a "Pre Release" tab.

Both of my tutorials show pictures like this:
[image]

Though clicking on my app in iTunesConnect brings up a page like this:
[image]

Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to go to the "TestFlight" tab in the new interface of iTunes Connect.
After you can select the build you want to enable for TestFlight, and add some internal testers (up to 25) or external testers (which will need Apple validation)

[image]

Comment: Okay. I've already done that, so it seems I'm going in the right direction.
Has the interface just been updated since the blogger wrote that tutorial or something?

Comment: Apple revamped the interface about two weeks ago. I uploaded three apps with the "new" interface, then went back about 5 days later and it had all changed. Again!

Comment: Yes, iTunesConnect has changed like a week ago. This is probably why your tutorial is not updated yet. To continue with testFlight, just add an internal user for TestFlight, but it may require that you have an "Admin" role for your iTunesConnect account.